# PHP environmental variables are null through the web server

Tags: php, docker, nginx, web, webserver

I am using docker to create a container with the *centOS* in which I have a *nginx* web server. I have a bunch of environmental variables that were declared in the docker-compose file (e.g. **`APP_ENV=docker`**).

When I access one site from the web server every environmental variable that was from the docker-compose file is ***null*** (I have tried `getenv()`, `$_SERVER[]`, `$_ENV[]`).

Interestingly enough, when I run `echo $APP_ENV` in the bash I get **docker**. More interestingly, when I run this `echo(_ENV['APP_ENV']);` I get **docker**. I use the phpstorm IDE.

I ran the `echo(_ENV['APP_ENV']);` when I ran the php shell in the bash.

Comment: Show your compose file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MK3KLwhd here it is